# [Dropbox-chooser api]Unable to jump to my app after the dropbox generated the link

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, openurl

My app authorizes Dropbox, which has always been good. Recently, I found that I could not jump back to my app after choosing files in Dropbox to generate links.
Below is the code in my app RRDocsController:

```
DBChooser *chooser = [[DBChooser defaultChooser] initWithAppKey:kDropboxAppKey];
        [chooser openChooserForLinkType:DBChooserLinkTypePreview fromViewController:self completion:^(NSArray *results) {
            if ([results count]) {
                //do somthings...
            }
        }];
```

Below is the code in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([[[DBChooser defaultChooser]initWithAppKey:kDropboxAppKey] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

if ([[[DBChooser defaultChooser] initWithAppKey:kDropboxAppKey] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    return YES;
}
return NO;}
```

**Supplement:**
When from my app jump to Dropbox, after the file selection page select files, pop-up "was generating links..." box, then the pop-up box and selection page dismiss together, but it can't to jump to my app, breakpoint tracking not callback in the appdelegate handleOpenURL: method, and the console doesn't have any log.

My phone is iPhone6 with iOS 10.3

Comment: check whether if ([[[DBChooser defaultChooser] initWithAppKey:kDropboxAppKey] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    return YES;
} is returning YES or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean when you say you "could not jump back to my app"? Are you just left in the official Dropbox app? Is there some error?

Comment: When from my app jump to Dropbox, after the file selection page select files, pop-up "was generating links..." box, then the pop-up box and selection page dismiss together, but it can't to jump to my app, breakpoint tracking not callback in the appdelegate handleOpenURL: method, and the console doesn't have any log.

Comment: My phone is iPhone6 with iOS 10.3